# Field made of real&imaginary parts of members of another field

Tags: galois-theory

Let ${\mathbb K}$ be a normal extension of $\mathbb Q$. Let $\mathbb L$ be the subfield of ${\mathbb C}$ generated by the real and imaginary parts of elements of $\mathbb K$. Thus $\mathbb L$ is a subfield of $\mathbb R$. Must $\mathbb L$ be a normal extension of $\mathbb Q$ also ?

Comment: If $i\sqrt7\in \Bbb{K}$, is it your intention that $\sqrt7\in\Bbb{L}$? Or in other words, do you chop the $i$ factor off the imaginary parts or not?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I'm surprised you should ask that, because in every definition I’ve seen, the imaginary part is a real number, the $i$ is always "chopped off". I've never seen a book or article that uses ${\mathfrak Im}(z)$ to denote a purely imaginary number.

Comment: Ok. Sure. I was just confused for a moment. May be the late hour :-)

Comment: What if $\Bbb{K}=\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of2,\sqrt{-3})$? Then $\root3\of2\in\Bbb{L}$, but its conjugates are not real, so they are $\notin\Bbb{L}$. Did I misunderstand something else? OTOH if you wanted $\Bbb{L}$ to be gotten from $\Bbb{K}$ by adjoining the real and imaginary parts, then $\Bbb{L}=\Bbb{K}(i)$, and that is normal as a compositum of two Galois extensions.

Comment: Hmm. The argument about compositum of Galois extensions may assume that the extensions are finite. Not sure about the infinite case.

Comment: Oh. And I hope you get the problem with your account sorted out.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You’re right, your $\mathbb K$ is a counterexample and answers my question.

Comment: Ok. I was initially thinking about the wrong problem, because a few years ago I actually needed to get a hold of the field we get by adjoining the $bi$:s instead of the $b$s :-)